# Upgrade Postgres on Jenkins CI Server from 9.1.9 to 9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, jenkins

I have a Jenkins CI server on Ubuntu 1204 that runs a number of rails rspec jobs.

What is the quickest and easiest way to upgrade the postgres server from 9.1.9 to 9.3.

The existing test databases on this server do not need to be saved when moving from 9.1.9 to 9.3

Kind Regards

Gurdipe

Comment: Please check this script: https://gist.github.com/mdpatrick/8895813

Comment: Here is comprehensive description about postgers update:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60465/upgrading-from-postgres-9-1-to-9-3-on-ubuntu-server

Answer (score 0):

As read in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) :

> Major releases usually change the internal format of system tables and
>   data files. These changes are often complex, so we do not maintain
>   backward compatibility of all stored data. A dump/reload of the
>   database or use of the [pg_upgrade](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html) module is required for major
>   upgrades.

So you should either :

- dump your data, install the new postgresql instance, reload data in
  your new instance, or
- use pg_upgrade to upgrade your existing data.